# Exe crashes in BackupRead Windows function

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, backup

The Below is my C++ code I tried to back up a file, including the security information. I used Backup read but whenever the code is called the exe is getting crashed.

```
char buff[225280];
DWORD numberOfBytesToRead = 225280;
DWORD dwBytesRead=0, dwBytesWritten, dwBytesRead2=0;
BOOL bProcessSecurity = TRUE;
LPWSTR sourceBackupFile = L"E:\\myFolder\\backup.txt";
HANDLE source = CreateFile(sourceBackupFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
// Check for errors
if (source == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
 cout<<"The Handle is Invalid:"<<GetLastError()<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<< "\n The source file is in E:\\myFolder\\backup.txt" <<endl ;
}
LPDWORD numberofbytedsreadinreadFile = 0;

cout << "Point Of Crash" << endl;
if (!BackupRead(
        source,
         &buff,
        numberOfBytesToRead,
        numberofbytedsreadinreadFile,
        FALSE,
        TRUE,
        NULL
        ))
     {

         cout << "Backup Read Failed with the error::" << GetLastError() << endl ;

     }
```

It prints this before crashing

```
The source file is in E:\\myFolder\\backup.txt
"Point of Crash"
```

Comment: What does it print before crashing? invalid handle, or valid source file? You shouldn't try to do anything with an invalid handle.

Comment: it prints "Point of Crash" before crashing nothing else. I just tried to open the handle and i didn't use it for anything. I closed the handle after that. I guess its not a concern since it breaks before that

Comment: The handle is used as a parameter for BackupRead. Your program should print one of the couts before point of crash based on your source code.

Comment: Sorry i edited the question it prints "The source file is in E:\\myFolder\\backup.txt" and "Point of Crash" before crashing

Comment: Just noticed that you call CreateFile. Do you want to read from `backup.txt`, or write to it?

Comment: I am just reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed `NULL` as the last parameter to `BackupRead`, which is clearly invalid acording to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362509(v=vs.85).aspx).

> lpContext [out] Pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to an
>   internal data structure used by BackupRead to maintain context
>   information during a backup operation. You must set the variable
>   pointed to by lpContext to NULL before the first call to BackupRead
>   for the specified file or directory. The function allocates memory for
>   the data structure, and then sets the variable to point to that
>   structure. You must not change lpContext or the variable that it
>   points to between calls to BackupRead. To release the memory used by
>   the data structure, call BackupRead with the bAbort parameter set to
>   TRUE when the backup operation is complete.

You should pass a pointer to a pointer to it, which points to null, not a null value. (`LPVOID` is `void*`, `LPVOID**` means `void**`)

Same with `numberofbytedsreadinreadFile`: you should pass a parameter to an existing variable, not a null pointer, it is an out parameter.

```
 void* backupContext = NULL;
 int   numberOfBytesRead = 0;
 cout << "Point Of Crash" << endl;
 if (!BackupRead(
                source,
                 &buff,
                numberOfBytesToRead,
                &numberOfBytesRead,
                FALSE,
                TRUE,
                &backupContext 
                ))
```

You should also return from this method if you got an invalid handle instead of continuing.

Comment: I have set the  void* backupContext = NULL; which you have mentioned still it is crashing.

Comment: That means one of your other parameters is still wrong. For example `source`, as I asked in comments.

Comment: The Handle is valid since i didn't get any error in that.

Comment: And you had another null pointer I didn't notice before. Please read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Are you saying about BackupRead